# Transition matrix of a single type branching process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

> Show that the branching process $\{X_n\}_{n\ge1}$ is a MC with state space $\mathbb{N}^+\cup\{0\}$. Find its transition matrix.

The first part is easy and I could do it in two steps-

1. Proved that $\mathbb{P}[X_{n+1}=s_{n+1}|X_n=s_n]=\mathbb{P}[X_{n+1}=s_{n+1}]$
2. Proved that $\mathbb{P}[X_{n+1}=s_{n+1}|X_n=s_n,...X_1=s_1]=\mathbb{P}[X_{n+1}=s_{n+1}]$

using the independence of $\{Y_{ij}\}_{i,j}$ which is the number of offsprings of the $j$th indiviudal in $i$th generation.

For transition matrix, I need to find $\mathbb{P}[X_n=s_n|X_m=s_m]$ for any $n,m$. Using
$$\mathbb{P}[X_{n+1}=s_{n+1}|X_n=s_n]=\mathbb{P}\left[\sum_{j=1}^{s_n}Y_{n,j}|X_n=s_n\right]$$
how do I calculate what is needed?

Comment: Are you familiar with convolutions? The distribution of the sum of $n$ i.i.d. r.v.'s is the $n-$fold convolution of the common distribution.

Comment: @geetha290krm Not exactly, but if that is the only way to prove this I'll read up on it. Could you show the corresponding proof please?

Comment: That is  the only way, unfortunately. There is no other way of writing the transition matrix. You can read Branching Processes by Athreya and Ney.

Comment: @geetha290krm it is written that the transtion matrix is such that $$p_{ij}^{(n)}=\mathbb{P}[\sum_{r=1}^{i}Y_{n,r}=j]\text{ and }p^{(n)}_{00}=1.$$ How do I need to simplify this more as a solution to finding the transition matrix using pmf of $Y$ if even possible to do so?

Comment: What you write in 1. and 2.  is incorrect.  The LHS of 1. and 2. are equal, that is the Markov property.